# python iterating the element in

Tags: python, list, dictionary, syntax

```
 dict = {46:  [{'picker_name': 'Table_1', 'picker_id': 970}], 
    47:  [{'picker_name': 'Table_7', 'picker_id': 994}, {'picker_name': 'Table_9', 'picker_id': 999}]}
```

i want to access **the only picker_id** of every key
for answer of this quetion :- **46 : 970, 47 : 994, 999**
i also try but i did not get right logic pls help me i am stuck from very long. i am newbie in python

these my logic :-

```
for key in dict:
    for i in range(len(dict[key])):
        for it in dict[key][i].values():
            print(it)
```

i got the output of this is :-

```
Table_1
970
Table_7
994
Table_9
999
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two iterations will work here, you do not need to use `range()`

```
d = {46:  [{'picker_name': 'Table_1', 'picker_id': 970}], 
47:  [{'picker_name': 'Table_7', 'picker_id': 994}, {'picker_name': 'Table_9', 'picker_id': 999}]}

for k, v in d.items():
    for d in v:
        print(k, d['picker_id'])
```

---

Output

```
46 970
47 994
47 999
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using map

```
d = {46:  [{'picker_name': 'Table_1', 'picker_id': 970}],
     47:  [{'picker_name': 'Table_7', 'picker_id': 994}, {'picker_name': 'Table_9', 'picker_id': 999}]}

res = {}
for key, pickers in d.items():
    res[key] = list(map(lambda picker: picker['picker_id'], pickers))
print(res) #{46: [970], 47: [994, 999]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try my best to clear the concept.
First of all, loop in the dictionary using .items() returns a dictionary view object that provides a dynamic view of dictionary elements as a list of key-value pairs.

```
dict_items([(46, [{'picker_name': 'Table_1', 'picker_id': 970}]), (47, [{'picker_name': 'Table_7', 'picker_id': 994}, {'picker_name': 'Table_9', 'picker_id': 999}])])
```

In the loop below the key will hold the first value i.e. 46 and the **value** will hold the second item which is the list.

Now run the loop in the value list. The elements represent each element in the list. Since the each element of the list is a dictionary, you can access the value of the 'picked_id' using the key 'picked_id'.

```
for key,value in dict.items():
    for elements in value:
        print(key,elements['picker_id'])
```

I hope this helps! All The Best! Good Luck on learning Python.

OutPut:

```
46 970
47 994
47 999
```